# Downgrade PHP 5.4.17 to 5.3.x OSX Mavericks

Tags: php, osx-mavericks

Is there a safe way to downgrade the PHP version on OSX Mavericks to 5.3.x without destroying anything badly?

Is there a remove package command or something like that? Apple has upgraded the default PHP version to 5.4.17.

Thanks so much, since I can't find the answer anywhere (yet).

-- edit --
What I have done so so far:

- Looked for information about downgrading PHP versions on OSX in general (since there are no specific articles about this for OSX mavericks. That didn't gave me the results I looked for. I did not call Apple because, well really Hakre, are you serious?
- I concidered installing a program like MAMP, but I decided I'd better try to keep my system as clean as possible without running multiple apaches at the same time next to each other.

And Hakre, I think many people will find this question usefull in the future because 5.4 is not really common in production environments.

Comment: Please define "destroying anything badly". What did you try so far, how did that turn out in terms of destruction? And more importantly: Why couldn't the technical support hotline of your operating system contractor tell you?

Answer (score 2):

You can use brew (http://brew.sh/) to install the PHP version that you wish. You can also have several versions of PHP and use the one you like. More info: https://github.com/josegonzalez/homebrew-php

Comment: Yes you can also fly to the moon with the right vehicle (link pending). And then run these scripts there. Recommended reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: I have followed your link and got myself brew installed. Also i have tapped into the homebrew-php. I have entered a new LoadModule in httpd.conf file, pointed to the .so file of the homebrew module. At this moment the apache is not parsing php as php so I've got to figure out why that happens. My apache log says: (13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address[::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80 no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs I'm getting there, but I'm not sure when. Thanks for your reply pointing Homebrew

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/353462/13permission-denied-make-sock-could-not-bind-to-address-80-mac-os-lion

Comment: As it turned out I forgot to install additional PHP extentions. That was causing apache to fail at some point in parsing PHP

Answer (score 2):

@m4t1t0 pointed me in the right direction today. It was a rough road figuring brew out, figuring apache out.

**1. Download Brew first** (see @m4t1t0 link, I can't post it) **

**2. [Install Brew and tap into PHP](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/)**

I'd like to point to this [excellent tutorial](http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/) of Justin Hileman on how to install PHP via brew. I'd like to advise anyone to follow his **steps by the letter**.

One caveat (not related to the main issue, but it took me some time to figure it out):

Check in the php the short_open_tag value. In my case I'm dealing with a lot of projects using the short version of the php tag. This setting might be turned off where you'd expected it to be set to On.